# jButton with a very strange behaviour

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

I've developed some desktop application, based on netbeans GUI creator, I'm facing strange problem with jButton behaviour, every time I click it, it acts 7 times:

```
jButton7.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
ButtonListener() {
}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("pushToTest")) {
            System.out.println("Button1 has been clicked");
            }
      }
}
```

and the output looks like:

```
Button1 has been clicked
Button1 has been clicked
Button1 has been clicked
Button1 has been clicked
Button1 has been clicked
Button1 has been clicked
Button1 has been clicked
```

just after one click. It happens to all of my buttons, I can't post gui's code, it's like 1700 lines, nobody would even bother reading it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact I'll make my comment an answer:

My guess -- your problem is in code not shown, and that you are likely adding the ActionListener to each JButton 7 times. Are you using for loops to do this? You'll need to check your code carefully, and right now, we can't help you since again, the offending code has not yet been shown.

Edit: your pastebin post suggests that you are in fact doing a lot of GUi initialization stuff inside of a for loop, this loop: `for (int ii = 0; ii < holder2.size() / 3; ii++) {`. Check out where the closing curly brace is:

```
         setComponent(mainPanel);
     setMenuBar(menuBar);
     setStatusBar(statusPanel);
  }// </editor-fold>  // *** here ***
```

And there is a ***ton*** of code between these braces including most all of your GUI initialization code. This is likely what is causing you to add your ActionListener 7 times to your button. My guess is that you really don't want the for loop to call all that code, that your mistake was in not adding the loop's end brace at the right spot.

Also, consider re-factoring that monster program and use variable names that make logical sense, and you will find that it will be much easier to debug your program. Same for us.

Comment: well in fact I'm not = /. This is not done by loop or anything, but by netBeans tool ' events -> action -> ...

Comment: Regardless, if that is the out put from a button press, and if that is the ActionListener class code, the *only* possible answer is that the listener has been added multiple times. Post your code to pastebin, let's see.

Comment: To test this hypothesis, put a `System.out.println("I have been created");` in the ButtonListener constructor.  That will tell you if you are creating and adding more than one listener.

Comment: I've done as You told me to, I've put the line in the constructor, and during the start of program it give 7 "times I've been created"

Comment: @iie: so yeah, you're adding the action listener 7 times.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RBEK3rS9

firstly, You don't have to dig through this code, I know it is kind of ....... but I'm doing it ASAP, for yesterday, just to show the plsql working properly. So sorry for thits "quality"

Comment: the thing is, that I do not add this listener 7 times, just once [ jbutton7 ]

Comment: @iie: yep, my guess was correct. See edit above. As a side note, consider refactoring that huge program of yours, and using variable names that make the code self-commenting.

Comment: @iie: you're welcome. Please let us know if this fixes your problem.